# Solucionar problema de Loop en una función en R

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio, reshape

He estado trabajando en un código el cual tiene como objetivo el recuperar una planilla excel de mis documentos, eliminar las filas y columnas innecesarias y luego realizarle un reshape de wide form to long form para luego guardar ese proceso en una nueva planilla de excel. Para mejorar los tiempos, hice una función que aplica en cada una de las partes correspondiente el cambio que necesito (esto dado que llegan a ser bastantes documentos a los cuales debo realizarles este proceso, dejaré mi código para que verifiquen el proceso:

```
#*************** Data Brazil Paper *****************#
# Funcion del reshape de excel de Economatica (data Brasil)
reshape_brazil <- function(dir,file,var,path,name) {
  
  # Cargamos las librerías a utilizar
  suppressPackageStartupMessages({
    library(tidyverse) # Nucleo de R
    library(readxl) # Lector de documentos excel
    library(openxlsx) # Generador de documentos Excel
    library(data.table) # Para generar el Reshape
  })
  
  # Deshabilitamos los mensajes de Error
  options(warn = -1)
  
  var <- as.character(var)
  
  # recordar siempre definir el directorio de trabajo
  setwd(dir)
  
  # cargamos la base de datos en formato excel
  df <- read_excel(file,
                   range = "B10:CQ671")
  df <- as.data.frame(df)
  
  # Eliminamos la primera fila de nuestra base de datos
  df <- df[-1,]
  
  # Eliminamos variables que no son necesarias en el Reshape
  df[,c(1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)] = NULL # 1- tic bolsa 2- tic 4- rut 5- naic 6- ...6 7- var_name122022 8- var_name92022
  
  # Hacemos reshape de wide to long format
  data.long <- melt(df, id.vars = "nombre", variable.name = "Caracteristica", value.name = var)
  
  # Ordenamos segun el nombre
  data.long <- data.long[order(data.long$nombre),]
  
  # Tranformamos el vector en Numérico
  data.long[,3] <- as.numeric(data.long[,3])
  
  setwd(path)
  
  # Guardamos la data en formato excel
  write.xlsx(data.long,   # Data frame a ser exportado
             name,                 # Ruta completa
             sheetName = var,   # Nombre de la hoja de Excel
             col.names = TRUE,     # Incluir los nombres de las columnas (TRUE) o no (FALSE)
             row.names = TRUE,     # Incluir los nombres de las filas (TRUE) o no (FALSE)
             append = FALSE,       # Agregar a un archivo existente (TRUE) o no (FALSE)
             showNA = TRUE,        # Si TRUE, los NA serán celdas vacías
             password = NULL)      # Contraseña como cadena de caracteres
  
}
```

Luego de esto, probé la misma función asignandole las rutas y nombres de las variables correspondientes, logrando funcionar como necesito, adjunto imagenes:

## ANTES:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## DESPUES:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, para poder optimizar los tiempos y dejar un script util para mas adelante, intenté realizar un loop sobre la misma función generada creando 3 variables listas, en las cuales estan presentes los valores para cada una de las iteraciones, adjunto listados:

```
# Lista de Variables
vars <- list(c("Cash","TotalAssets","TotalLiability","NetIncome","CurrAssets","CurrLiab","Revenues","MarketCapitaliz","Capex","DivPaid","PPENet","ConsolNetInc","StckhEq"))

# Lista de Archivos excel
files <- list(c("Brazil_Cash.xlsx","Brazil_TotalAssets.xlsx","Brazil_TotalLiability.xlsx","Brazil_NetIncome.xlsx","Brazil_CurrAssets.xlsx","Brazil_CurrLiab.xlsx","Brazil_Revenues.xlsx","Brazil_MarketCapitaliz.xlsx","Brazil_Capex.xlsx","Brazil_DivPaid.xlsx","Brazil_PPENet.xlsx","Brazil_ConsolNetInc.xlsx","Brazil_StckhEq.xlsx"))

# Lista de Archivos excel a exportar en formato long reshape
names <- list(c("Long_Brazil_Cash.xlsx","Long_Brazil_TotalAssets.xlsx","Long_Brazil_TotalLiability.xlsx","Long_Brazil_NetIncome.xlsx","Long_Brazil_CurrAssets.xlsx","Long_Brazil_CurrLiab.xlsx","Long_Brazil_Revenues.xlsx","Long_Brazil_MarketCapitaliz.xlsx","Long_Brazil_Capex.xlsx","Long_Brazil_DivPaid.xlsx","Long_Brazil_PPENet.xlsx","Long_Brazil_ConsolNetInc.xlsx","Long_Brazil_StckhEq.xlsx"))
```

Con ello ya definido, realicé el correspondiente loop para que realice el proceso autromaticamente, aquí el código:

```
for (n in names) {
  for (f in files) {
    for (v in vars) {
reshape_brazil(dir = "C:/Users/matias/Documents/LabFenUAH/Brazil_data/Data", # Directorio de Trabajo
               file = f, # Archivo Excel a usar
               var = v, # Nombre de la Variable en el Reshape
               path = "C:/Users/matias/Documents/LabFenUAH/Brazil_data/Long Data",
               name = n) # Directorio de ubicación (incluyendo el nombre del archivo que se quiere en el excel con termino en .xlsx)
    }
  }
}
```

Pero a la hora de correr este loop, me sale el siguiente error en la consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto? me cae la duda dado que la variable path de mi función esta descrita como un string fijo, porque esa es la ruta en la cual quiero que queden los archivos.

Muchas gracias!

Como ya comente mas arriba, intente generar el proceso fijo, es decir, que el path sea un valor, pero no comprendo mas alla del como puedo abordar este problema.

Comment: Prueba definiendo las variables, archivos y nombres solo como vectores y no como una lista con un vector. P.e. usa `vars <- c(...)` en lugar de `vars <- list(c(...))`.

Comment: @RolandoTamayo gracias amigo, eso me ayudo, pero ahora tengo otro problema, el loop funciona, pero se queda solo en la carga de los documentos, no avanza en el reshape que pido ni tampoco en guardar la base de reshape long en la ruta especificada, ¿sabes como podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2):

Primero define las variables, archivos y nombres como vectores no como listas, luego el problema me parece que es en el loop aninado entre names, var y files, teoricamente lo que esta realizando es tomar el primer elemento de names, luego tomar el primer elemento de files, y de ahi pasa todas las variables a cada name y file; pero lo que debería realizar es simultaneamente pasar cada elemento de names, files y vars. Prueba lo siguiente utilizando indices:

```
for (n in seq_along(names)) {
reshape_brazil(dir = "C:/Users/matias/Documents/LabFenUAH/Brazil_data/Data", # Directorio de Trabajo
               file = files[n], # Archivo Excel a usar
               var = vars[n], # Nombre de la Variable en el Reshape
               path = "C:/Users/matias/Documents/LabFenUAH/Brazil_data/Long Data",
               name = names[n]) # Directorio de ubicación (incluyendo el nombre del archivo que se quiere en el excel con termino en .xlsx)
    }
```

Comment: gracias! @dvera, fue de mucha ayuda tu comentario, efectivamente mi loop estaba lejos de ser optimo, gracias por el apoyo!

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que entiendo, cuando haces esto:

```
files <- list(c("Brazil_Cash.xlsx","Brazil_TotalAssets.xlsx","Brazil_TotalLiability.xlsx",
                "Brazil_NetIncome.xlsx","Brazil_CurrAssets.xlsx","Brazil_CurrLiab.xlsx",
                "Brazil_Revenues.xlsx","Brazil_MarketCapitaliz.xlsx","Brazil_Capex.xlsx",
                "Brazil_DivPaid.xlsx","Brazil_PPENet.xlsx","Brazil_ConsolNetInc.xlsx",
                "Brazil_StckhEq.xlsx"))
```

Estas suponiendo que se crea una lista dónde cada elemento es un nombre de archivo, pero en realidad, lo que se genera es una lista con un solo elemento, el vector de países, puedes verificarlo:

```
files
[[1]]
 [1] "Brazil_Cash.xlsx"           
 [2] "Brazil_TotalAssets.xlsx"    
 [3] "Brazil_TotalLiability.xlsx" 
 [4] "Brazil_NetIncome.xlsx"      
 [5] "Brazil_CurrAssets.xlsx"     
 [6] "Brazil_CurrLiab.xlsx"       
 [7] "Brazil_Revenues.xlsx"       
 [8] "Brazil_MarketCapitaliz.xlsx"
 [9] "Brazil_Capex.xlsx"          
[10] "Brazil_DivPaid.xlsx"        
[11] "Brazil_PPENet.xlsx"         
[12] "Brazil_ConsolNetInc.xlsx"   
[13] "Brazil_StckhEq.xlsx"
```

El `[[1]]` te está indicando el elemento 1 de la lista y dentro de éste esta el vector con los 13 nombres. De esta forma cuando haces: `for (f in files)`, solo se itera por el único elemento, y `f` termina siendo un vector con 13 cadenas que se lo envías a `read_excel()` que con certeza te dice que `path`  tiene que ser una cadena (no un vector).

La solución a este problema, como ya te comentaron es trabajar directamente con el vector y no con la lista, o bien construir la lista de forma adecuada:

```
files <- as.list(c("Brazil_Cash.xlsx","Brazil_TotalAssets.xlsx","Brazil_TotalLiability.xlsx",
                   "Brazil_NetIncome.xlsx","Brazil_CurrAssets.xlsx","Brazil_CurrLiab.xlsx",
                   "Brazil_Revenues.xlsx","Brazil_MarketCapitaliz.xlsx","Brazil_Capex.xlsx",
                   "Brazil_DivPaid.xlsx","Brazil_PPENet.xlsx","Brazil_ConsolNetInc.xlsx",
                   "Brazil_StckhEq.xlsx"))

files
[[1]]
[1] "Brazil_Cash.xlsx"

[[2]]
[1] "Brazil_TotalAssets.xlsx"

[[3]]
[1] "Brazil_TotalLiability.xlsx"

[[4]]
[1] "Brazil_NetIncome.xlsx"

[[5]]
[1] "Brazil_CurrAssets.xlsx"

[[6]]
[1] "Brazil_CurrLiab.xlsx"

[[7]]
[1] "Brazil_Revenues.xlsx"

[[8]]
[1] "Brazil_MarketCapitaliz.xlsx"

[[9]]
[1] "Brazil_Capex.xlsx"

[[10]]
[1] "Brazil_DivPaid.xlsx"

[[11]]
[1] "Brazil_PPENet.xlsx"

[[12]]
[1] "Brazil_ConsolNetInc.xlsx"

[[13]]
[1] "Brazil_StckhEq.xlsx"
```

Por último, revisa la lógica ¿Es correcto anidar tres ciclos? En realidad, por lo que entiendo o imagino, deberían ser un único ciclo con 13 iteraciones.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda en la correción de la lista, efectivamente, el formato que estaba usando era el incorrecto. Ahora ya lo logré solucionar!